# Correct translation of "Спросите вы" from Russian to English

Tags: translation

I want to translate Russian anti-war piece of poetry:

> Хотят ли русские войны?
>
> Спросите вы у тишины
>
> Над ширью пашен и полей,
>
> И у берёз, и тополей.
>
> Спросите вы у тех солдат,
>
> Что под берёзами лежат,
>
> И вам ответят их сыны,
>
> Хотят ли русские войны.
>
> Евгений Евтушенко, 1961 г.

There is repeated segment of this poetry: "**Спросите вы**". How to translate it on English precisely?
Meaning is *plea, suggestion to listener to ask* "those soldiers".

1. Is "**You'll ask** those soldiers" right? Ot at least fine / okay?
2. What is correct way to translate it? I thought about "Please ask those soldiers", but original phrase does not carry such gentleness, politeness, as word "Please" does.

Comment: Not sure if this type of question is invited here, but can you give more of the translated context? I think just "Ask those solders" would be best. "You" is not needed as it is an [**understood subject**](https://philosophy-question.com/library/lecture/read/289696-which-word-is-the-understood-subject-in-this-sentence#:~:text=Understood%20Subject%3A%20A%20sentence%20has%20an%20understood%20subject,pronoun%20you.%20%28Example%3A%20Stand%20quietly%20in%20the%20line.%29).

Comment: @EliHarold 
 Feedback is useful! 
 Context: author asks rethorical question in the first sentence of poetry: 
"Do Russians want to have a war?" 
And then suggest to listeners to ask "silence" and "those soldiers who now lie under birches"  to have an answer on this question

Comment: Yeah it seems to me like "Ask those solders" is what you want. Here are [more examples](https://www.thoughtco.com/you-understood-grammar-1692618) of understood subjects.

Comment: Still struggling to have answers on two questions in original post.

Comment: About "Ask those soldiers": what confuses me, original line has "_you_" purposely "Спросите _вы_ у тишины". I think to elongate phrase from rhythmic perspective.

Comment: *You'll ask those soldiers*, will probably be heard as a question and if not, then possibly as a command.  It does not sound like a *plea*.  I would use ***Go and ask** those soldiers [lying under birches].*  *Go and [verb]* is a common poetic imploration.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is requesting translation guidance.

Comment: Not the first to ask about this...https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/312005/i-want-to-translate-russian-1961s-piece-of-anti-war-poetry-on-english

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about translation.

Comment: @Yaroslav Kadetov: **Do The Russians Want War** is a famous song with words by Yevtushenko. There are plenty of translations around - [here](https://ruverses.com/evgeny-evtushenko/do-the-russians-want-war/11761/), for example - and a Wikipedia article about it. Visitors to the USSR were offered the free pamphlet entitled "Do The Russians Want War?" on arrival.